# Importing specific variables from one file to another- Python

Tags: python

In WattTues2.py and WattWed2.py I have an input statement in there which is in a while loop. Now there are also specific variables in WattTues2.py that I want to copy to WattWed2.py so I do as what is in the picture, but the while loop and input statements from WattTues2.py also run in WattWed2.py now, how can i stop this?[image]

Comment: 1. it is not good to [post a very similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61861355/2648551) without mention this one there. 2. it is not good to show a picture of the code. Instead copy/paste the code and [format it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). 3. It is not good to [hide relevant code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like the relevant parts in `WattWed2.py`. This question leads to unnecessary work for the ones who want try to help you. So it would be nice if you could edit your question and make the work for others more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that solution to your problem is moving some code to. For example:

a.py:

```py
aa = 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('This is a.py')
```

b.py:

```py
from a import aa

print(aa)
```

Comment: I am confused to what you mean, could u show me fully what i need to type sorry. I tried just how you typed it but it did the same thing still

Comment: Ok, but first show [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok so pretty much, it imports everything from that file as if i had written  import *  but i only want those specific variables to import